# I am trying to use the code to create graphs in MATLAB but its not working

Tags: matlab

I need help with my Matlab code. It is not working, it keeps giving me errors on the same line. I don't know how to fix it, can you please help? I am trying to make graphs in Matlab.

```matlab
clc
num=(1);
dem=[1 3 10 0];
Ls=tf(num,dem);
relocus(Ls)
```

The error is:

```
Error in Matlab (line 4)
Ls=tf(num,dem);
```

Comment: can someone  please help

Comment: I have the solution, but: what's exactly the error? Do you understand that's hard to answer this question if it isnt clear?

Comment: try correcting the name of the function call: `relocus` doesn't exist if you try with `rlocus` everithing it's gonna be allright..

Comment: the error is for the Ls=tf(num,dem); code  it keeps saying error in line 4 which is the code Ls=tf(num,dem);

Comment: matlab does not only say "error in line..." also provide a more detailed info of the error. what does it say?

Comment: I tried changing the name but it still does not work

Comment: the error is this Undefined function 'tf' for input arguments of type 'double'. and if possible can you paste your code that worked.

Comment: maybe you have in workspace a variable called tf that is overwriting the tf function and that's why you have an error? it's hard to know WITHOUT ALL THE ERROR MESSAGE. try `clear all` at start of code

Comment: Unrecognized function or variable 'Clear'.

Error in rlocus (line 1)
Clear all;

Comment: `clear all` lowercase! I writed lowercase, because it goes lowercase

Comment: its not working

Comment: it says Error in rlocus (line 5)

Comment: could you add some screenshot of your editor and workspace? it's hard to debug with half or less of the information...

Comment: its not allowing me to add screen shotes

Comment: edit the question, add the screens there

Comment: I tried I can't I am a new user so it tells me that I need 10 points or something to add screenshots. is it possible if you can write the code correctly and then paste it here. i can send the question for my assignment but it does not let me attach sreenshots.

Comment: it says that I need to earn 10 reputations in order to attach images.

Comment: You typed `relocus` instead of `rlocus` in line 5.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include the code you ran (properly formatted) and the **full** error message, including the stack trace. We cannot help if we don’t know what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

Correct the function 'relocus' to 'rlocus'.

```
num=(1);
dem=[1 3 10 0];
Ls=tf(num,dem);
rlocus(Ls)
clc
```